# In JAVA Finding File by name(any extension) from all drive of computer

Tags: java

can anyone explain me, how i can find particular file from computer?

[image]

When i click the search button then output should show me all the path who have sample file with any extension.

please help me. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The java.nio.file package provides programmatic support for this useful feature. Each file system implementation provides a PathMatcher. You can retrieve a file system's PathMatcher by using the getPathMatcher(String) method in the FileSystem class. The following code snippet fetches the path matcher for the default file system:

```
String pattern = ...;
PathMatcher matcher =
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
```

and create PathMatcher instance like -

```
PathMatcher matcher =
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.{java,class}");

Path filename = ...;
if (matcher.matches(filename)) {
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

See this for working example. (to get path you have to get PathMatcher's relative path.)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

UPDATE -

for my computer, you have to loop thru all the drives one by one, and take drive letter as path i.e `D:\` will become your path. The above code will work fine for specific path.